# Drag & Drop из проводника в TreeView

Tags: c#, wpf, explorer, drag-n-drop

Есть иерархическая структура TreeView с TreeViewItem, для каждого TreeViewItem нужно разрешить перетаскивание файла из проводника и сохранять ссылку на этот файл (полный путь до файла).

В TreeView установил свойство AllowDrop = true, таким образом разрешил перетаскивание объектов в него.

Для каждого TreeViewItem привязал обработчик Drop, в котором осуществляю привязку объекта в узлу дерева.

Не понимаю, как сделать обработчик и у кого его делать необходимо, чтобы курсор мыши менялся в зависимости от того, какой файл сейчас кидают на ветку дерева?

Например, нужно разрешить привязку файлов только с расширением .txt, остальные файлы запретить.

Пытался сделать для TreeViewItem через событие PreviewDropEnter проверку, и если файл имел другое расширение, устанавливал e.Effect = DragDropEffects.None. Но курсор все равно не изменялся на запрет, оставался внешним видом похожим на DragDropEffects.Move

Как-то не так делаю обработку?

PS: TreeViewItem объект состоит из StackPanel внутри которого вложено пару textblock и image. В поведении проглядывается, что где-то между элементами курсор меняется на другой. Это получается нужно каждому вложенному элементу treeviewitem обработчики присвоить?

Comment: `PreviewDragEnter` срабатвает на границе элемента. Посмотри на `PreviewDragOver`, это событие срабатывает _"постоянно при перетаскивании объекта в границах элемента"_.

Comment: Обновил вопрос. Дело кроется в множестве вложенных элементов в treeviewitem. Как правильно draganddrop в этом случае организовать?

Comment: @pincher1519: Да, каждому вложенному. Насколько я помню, treeview в WPF построено рекурсивно. То есть вложенные куски не являются child-элементами. (Если что, можно небольшой воспроизводящий пример?)

Comment: @VladD попробую сделать пример и посмотреть, сюда же опубликую его

Comment: @MaLS, Действительно, необходимо было использовать дополнительно PreviewDragOver, в этом случае курсор корректно меняется для элемента дерева...